# A continuous function such that $f(x)=(f(x))^2$ for all $x$ is constant

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

> Let $f(x)=(f(x))^2$ that is continuous for every $x \in\mathbb  R$.
>
> Prove using the intermediate value theorem that this function is constant.

I noticed that the $f(x)$ could only be equal to : $1,0$

I know I can evaluate its limit at infinity:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$

$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=1$

Can I conclude anything from that that the function is constant?
I know there exist a $c\in R$ such that $1\le f(c) \le 1$, but exists is not proving that for all $c \in R$ :S

Can someone please arrange the mess I've done?:)

Thanks

Comment: How did you prove that the limits at infinity exist?

Comment: You said noting about the domain; if the domain consists of two disjoint intervals, what then? Maybe you didn't give the complete text of your exercise?

Comment: It's continuous for every $x \in R$

Comment: You already pretty much said it, it can only be 0 or 1, and it must be continuous so it has to be one or the other..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose image consists of finitely many points is constant.

Indeed, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and not constant, there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(a) < f(b)$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ will take all values in the interval $[f(a),f(b)]$, which are infinitely many values.

Answer (score 3):

To note that the only two possible values are $0$ and $1$ is a good start.

Whatever you did to get the limits is false.

Assume the function takes the value $0$ for some $x$ and $1$ for some $y$ and apply the intermediate value theorem to get a contradiction to the function taking only the values $0$ and $1$.

Then you will know the function is either constant $0$ or constant $1$.